# How to install Lotus Expeditor on Eclipse Keplar

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, composite-application

I am trying to develop composite applications for IBM Lotus Notes using Lotus Expeditor Toolkit.  I am using Eclipse Keplar SR2 and trying to install Lotus Expeditor 6.2.3 (and even 6.2.2 & 6.2.1).  I have downloaded the update site for Expeditor Toolkit:

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/nochargesearch.jsp?q=Lotus+Expeditor+Toolkit+6.2

Eclipse is able to see the site.xml file and attempts to install Expeditor but I get an error message that org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.4.0,3.5.0] is not found.

I downloaded Equinox for KeplarSR2:

http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-KeplerSR2-201402211700/index.php

I am able to download a zip file with folders for binary, features and plugins, but no site.xml doc, so Eclipse cannot install this way.  There is an artifacts.xml file, though, and a content.xml file.

How then can I install Equinox into Eclipse?  (With the goal of installing Lotus Expeditor)

And perhaps, do I even need Lotus Expeditor?  Are there other Java UI classes that will allow me to add menu items, for example, that I can hide or grey-out if the user mail file is not in focus?

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse already comes with Equinox built-in. Look at the version numbers and see if Kepler is an acceptable platform.

Comment: In Keplar, Equinox jars seem to be in org.eclipse.p2.equinox.common -- not sure what p2 is.

Comment: which version of Lotus Notes are you trying to develop for?

Answer (score 2):

Expediter 6.2.3 is dated Oct 11, 2011 so is probably built to work with a much older Eclipse base than Kepler SR2.  Given the error version range is [3.4.0,3.5.0) I would guess it's mean to work with Eclipse 3.4.2 (aka Ganymede) or possibly 3.5.2 (aka Helios).

If you're working with a newer Notes version then I expect Expediter is not the way any longer, but I don't know what to suggest.  I'll post again if I can find out.

Answer (score 2):

The [3.4.0,3.5.0] part of the message is telling you that Expeditor wants a version of the org.eclipse.equinox.common plugin that is between versions 3.4.0 and 3.5.0.

Eclipse Kepler (and Luna) have version 3.6.200 of this plugin so the Expeditor install is not compatible. Probably not surprising since the Expeditor download dates from 2011.

You will have to use an older version of Eclipse if you want to use this code.

p2, by the way, is Eclipse install manager.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those that responded.  I have confirmed that Lotus Expeditor works only with Eclipse Ganymede JavaEE IDE.